# How to increment names in python for state1,state2.....state10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

How can I increment the last string character in Python instead of writing the same thing 10 times

```
.
.
groupBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 15))
.
.
state1=  QtGui.QPushButton("xyz")
state2=  QtGui.QPushButton("124")
.
.
state10= QtGui.QPushButton("abc") # these stuff are to be assigned with different titles 

state1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10)
state2.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10)

.
```

I wanted to increment just here to apply the same font to all the items, something like the following (I need to have different fonts for my `GroupBox` and `QPushButton`)

```
for i in xrange(10):
        "state" + str(i).setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10))
```

Comment: The answers you're getting seem not to answer your question. It would help if you explained why you're creating discrete variables with similar names, rather than a list or dictionary.

Comment: @egrunin, I was  actually trying to create 10 different buttons, 10 titles, 10  status tips, i never implemented this with loops in python,  so wanted to give a try with the loops for doing this stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a list and then `append` and modify the data.

```
ButtonNames=['hello','world'] #fill this manually
Buttons=[]
for name in ButtonNames:
    Buttons.append(QtGui.QPushButton(name))
for btn in Buttons:
    btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10)
    vbox.addWidget(btn)

for k in xrange(0,len(ButtonNames)):
    Buttons[k].setTooltip("Click here for {}".format(ButtonNames[k])
```

What you're trying to do in your example is to call a method from a `string` object. Certainly, it doesn't exist, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: I was trying to use this , how should i proceed with adding the list widgets to `vbox.addWidget(Buttons)` as it takes only integers

Comment: @SaiGanesh, you can cycle through `Buttons` with `for Btn in Buttons:` and do `vbox.addWidget(btn)`

Comment: So far sooo good. Need to add extra features now .Can i iterate  two loops in parallel. i wanted something like `btn.setTooltip("click here for %s " % name)`   i.e. to add a tooltip for every button which shoud use the item names  from ButtonNames list

Comment: @SaiGanesh, why do you need to do this in parallel? See edit to my answer.

Comment: Perfect .overall it was good tutorial. i shrinked my code from 60 lines to ~10 lines

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested lists already (and I think that's a good way to do it) but in case you still need/want to be able to refer to the elements by names, you could also use a dictionary:

```
states = {'first':QtGui.QPushButton("xyz"),\
           'second':QtGui.QPushButton("124"),\
           'tenth':QtGui.QPushButton("bla")}

# looping over all:
for state in states.values():
    state.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10)

# addressing a single one:
states['second'].setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 12)
```

This way you can iterate over all of them easily but still give them names which may be easier to remember

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that per-se in python
but if `state1`..`state10` are members of an object you can do:

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
       for i in xrange(1,10):
           self.__dict__['state%d' % i] = QtGui.QPushButton("124")
```

But why would you want to do that? it's just ugly. Use a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could easily be solved using the `exec()` function:

```
.
.
groupBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 15))
.
for x in range(1,10):
    exec('state'+str(x)+'=  QtGui.QPushButton("Button'+str(x)+'")')
.
for x in range(1,10):
    exec('state'+str(x)+'.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10)')
.
.
```

That's what you were asking how do when you wrote:

```
for i in xrange(10):
        "state" + str(i).setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10))
```

The `exec()` function basically takes the string output of it's argument and runs it as a normal line of code. So your above snippet can be written as:

```
for i in xrange(10):
        exec("state" + str(i)+".setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 10))")
```